# Javascript Search function to highlight image

Tags: javascript, html

I have 100 images on a website, and I want to be able to search in the search box the file name of the image. After that for the image to be highlighted when found. Files are named 0-1.png, 0-2.png, etc. So if I type 0-1 to highlight image 0-1.png. Here is what I have so far.

```
<form  action='' method='get'>
<input type="text" name="search" size="3" maxlength="3">
<input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```

How do I create a Javascript function to search for image and highlight it?
Also images are stored in path like `images/0-1.png`

Comment: This sounds like something you should use Javascript for. If the image is already being displayed and you just want to highlight it there is definitely no reason to make a new request to the server.

Comment: yes that's what I really wanted to ask actually, what would be best. I have no knowledge  on search functions. Thanks I can edit this  question now.

Comment: if the file names of the images are as you mentioned, then will the `src` attrib of the `<img>` tag contain these filenames or will it also contain something like `/images/public/0-1.png`, that is some kinda path and then the name of the file??

Comment: yes they are in `images/0-1.png`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this may work for you:

```
<input type="text" id="search" />
<div id="images">
  <img src="0-1.png" />
  <img src="0-2.png" />
  ...
</div>
<script>
  (function(){
    var input = document.getElementById('search');
    var images = document.getElementById('images').getElementsByTagName('img');

    input.onkeyup = function(){
      for(var i = images.length; i--;){
          images[i].className = 
            images[i].src.indexOf(this.value) > 0 ?
            'highlight' :
            '';
      }       
   };
 })();
</script>
```

With this in your CSS:

```
img.highlight {
    border: 5px solid #F0F;
    margin: -5px;
}
```

[JsFiddle (with broken images)](http://jsfiddle.net/FZYgP/)

Comment: and what if my images are  stored in path `images/0-1.png` not `0-1.png`

Comment: @srtstripes My code just does a basic substring search, so it will still search. Basically it will highlight all images for which the current value in the `input` is a substring of the `src` property. If you just type `images` into the box it will highlight everything. If you just type `0-1` it would highlight things like `images/0-1.png` and `images/0-11.png`

Comment: Never mind its working. My div was called something else. Thank you

Comment: @srtstripes You're welcome, I hope you can tweak it to your liking. If you have any minor questions about it feel free to comment here again. If you have a question that could use a full answer, then you may as well ask it as a separate question. Good luck!

Comment: I  wanted to ask if I can change the onkeyup function. I would prefer if it would run after entering 3 keys into search field,  since 3 is the maxlength of the search. Reason being is because all the images change when I enter 1 key and messes up the css coding for images. You can see here why. http://jsfiddle.net/FZYgP/2/

Comment: Hi @srtstripes, rather than change the onkeyup you cam test if `this.value.length < 3`. I'd show you an example but I'm just on my phone right now. I might be able to write an example tomorrow when I have computer access

Answer (score 1):

Add a id="search" to your input name="search" textbox.  Include jquery.  Add the following code in your head statement.  Drop the search button

```
<script>
$(function() { 
    $('#search').keyup(function() {
        $('img')                     
            .removeClass('highlight')
            .filter('img[src*="'+$(this).val()+'"]')
            .addClass('highlight'); 
    });
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
img { border: 3px solid transparent; }
img.highlight { border-color: yellow; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fstreamz/8kCxw/3/

Comment: Yes this is something like I need. How do I include jquery

Comment: And would it matter if my images are stored in `images/0-1.png` path

Comment: Pick Paulpro as the answer.  His doesn't need jquery.

Comment: @LUKE You're answer may still be best, if it is more useful to the OP. If he wants to try learning jQuery, it could be very beneficial to him too. I would recommend though, that you set a `-3px` margin along with the border, just to make it so that the images don't shift when they are selected (and also don't cause elements around them to shift).

Comment: I didn't really care so much about those specifics.  Was just giving him an example.  Might be better for him to just hide all the images that match if there are a bunch.  I'll update my answer tho for future peeps.